# Model Update fails with no error

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm just trying to generate a user during the bootstrap process.

I hit his update statement and the  process stops, then times out after 10 seconds with "Bootstrap is taking unusually long to execute its callback (10000 milliseconds)."  Update error is never thrown. I know the user exists. I've checked before attempting update.

```
User.update({id:id}, {verificationCode: verificationCode})
    .then(function(updatedUser){
        console.log("VerificationCode added.", updatedUser);
        addInitialPermissions();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        if(err) throw new Error(err);
        next(err);
    });
```

I have no clue what the problem can be. Would appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: did you try my solution? I think it will work

Comment: @mryarbles Sounds like you're not calling the callback function `next()` in case of success. Can you post the code for `addInitialPermissions()`?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
User.update({id:id}, {verificationCode: verificationCode})
    .then(function(updatedUser){
        console.log("VerificationCode added.", updatedUser);
        addInitialPermissions();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        if(err) throw new Error(err);
        next(err);
    });
```

This is correct, **exec** , ***not then***:

```
User.update({id:id}, {verificationCode: verificationCode})
    .exec(function(err, updatedUser){
    if(err) {
     console.log(err)
    return;
    }
        console.log("VerificationCode added.", updatedUser);
        addInitialPermissions();
    });
```